# how to parse elements in a line into different hash tables?

Tags: java, hashmap

Assume I have a file with the following format for alphabets a-z:

```
a,9,1
b,2,4
*,0,2
```

and i have two hash maps namedly: hashA, hashB
now i need to write a code to make the alphabet a key and the number next to it a value. So it needs to be like this: hashA has (a,9) and hashB has (a,1)
My partial code is:

```
public static void constructLetterMaps() throws FileNotFoundException{
  File pointvals = new File(letterFileLoc);
  Scanner pts = new Scanner(pointvals);
  while (pts.hasNext()){
  char alpha = (pts.next()).charAt(0);
```

so how do i parse into different hash maps and follow it for each line.

Comment: You started good, don't give up and look for answers. Hint: instead of working with chars you can split the string by comma and get a string array with the 3 items. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could for example read the file line by line, split a line into an array of strings the it's quite straight forward to store the values as you want into differen `HashMaps`.

See some snippets to demonstrate the idea.

```
Map<String, String> hashA = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> hashB = new HashMap<>();

String line = "a,9,1"; // the line from the file
String[] parts = line.split(","); // split the lines into parts
hashA.put(parts[0], parts[1]); // put "a", "9"
hashB.put(parts[0], parts[2]); // put "a", "1"

System.out.println("hashA = " + hashA);
System.out.println("hashB = " + hashB);
```